# How to do code collaborative coding/team teamwork With GitHub and IDEs?

Tags: php, codeigniter, github, phpstorm, collaboration

We are a team of 2 web developers working on a same website Codeigniter framework. I am using PhpStorm while my team-mate uses Dreamveiwer for development and we have locally hosted the project on each others machines (backend & frontend). As we are working remotly and share code to each other by sharing files that causes integration and code loss/overwriting issues.

Now, I want know is there any system/tool (i.e Github or any other) where we can host our project and access to our machines where code do coding simultaneously, so we dont get the issues.

I am new to these terms, so help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"where code do coding simultaneously"

That would be easier with a tool like [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which includes "[Live Share](http://%20where%20code%20do%20coding%20simultaneously)" (as well as [CodeIgniter support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SetiawanJodi.myci-extension))

That way, you can:

- push your code to GitHub
- benefit from real-time code sharing session through Live Share.